# Use Apache server behind proxy server

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, proxy

I have apache2.4 webserver installed on ubuntu 14.04, which has all the configuration for the virtual host file.Also I have configured ssl certificates in it. But I want to run this apache server behind other proxy server which have different IP then the Web Server.

Please suggest me the best way to do this.I am planing to install another apache on the proxy server and achieve this using reverse-proxy.But Please suggest any better way to do this.

Thanks
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

I recently read some doc about setting up a reverse proxy server and it seems that ningx is a better choice than Apache for this task: it is very lightweight and really easy to configure. For example in a doc I read the writer could not manage to set up correct proxy for HTTPS for Apache, while another one trying the same configuration for nginx set it up easily. I am an old Apache fan, but if I had to install a proxy, I would chose nginx.